# E/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Couldn't encode request, returning with 400 crashlytics Error

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

````
     Crash details not updated in crashlytics dashboard in firebase console android,i Got Below Error
 ```
````

```
 I/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Making request to: https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog
```

E/TRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Couldn't encode request, returning with 400
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No X.509 TrustManager

```
 Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No X.509 TrustManager
```

```
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

```
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
```

```
Gradle(projectlevel)
```

```
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
```

```
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
```

Comment: These errors are usually related to network issues. Especially if you are behind a corporate network or a firewall. Have you tried using a different network? If so, does the issue remain?